# Close last opened workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My code right now opens an excel workbook, selected by the user, which I give to the `fileName` variable. I then open the `fileName` and copy it's content into another workbook. This is working.

Now I want to make it so that after copying, it closes the file in `fileName`

```
Sub importarRelatórioAtividade()
    Dim fileName As Variant
        
    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    If fileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=fileName
        Dim myrange As Range
        Set myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
        
        ' Find non-empty rows (check two columns)
        Dim n_rows_A As Long, n_rows_B As Long, n_rows As Long
        n_rows_A = CountRows(myrange)
        n_rows_B = CountRows(myrange.Offset(0, 1))
        n_rows = WorksheetFunction.Max(n_rows_A, n_rows_B)
        
        ' Do the copy here
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Análise").Range("A6").Resize(n_rows, 12).Value = _
                myrange.Resize(n_rows, 12).Value
                
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
    End If
End Sub

Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Objects. That ways it will be easier to handle it

Change

```
Workbooks.Open fileName:=fileName
```

To

```
Dim wbNew as Workbook
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
```

And in the end you can simply close it using

```
wbNew.Close '<~~ If changes are made then you will get a prompt to save
'wbNew.Close (True) '<~~ Save and close (No Saving Prompts)
'wbNew.Close (False) '<~~ Close without saving (No Saving Prompts)
```